# question about uniqueness of solution of initial value problem

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations

consider the IVP $$\dot{y}=\sqrt{|y|},y(x_0)=y_0$$ then it has two solutions namely 
y=0 and y=
\begin{cases}
\frac{x^2}{4},  & \text{if $x\ge0$} \\
-\frac{x^2}{4}, & \text{if $x\lt0$}  \\
\end{cases}
but on solving i found that it has solution $y=0$ and y=\begin{cases}
\frac{x^2}{4},  & \text{if $y\ge0$} \\
-\frac{x^2}{4}, & \text{if $y\lt0$}  \\
\end{cases}
i found it as $|y|=y$ if $y \ge 0$ and $|y|=-y$ if $y<0$ and doing integration can someone tell me where I am wrong how the case become at $x$ not on $y$.
$\bf EDIT$if we changes the initial condition as $y(0)=0$ then how to solve the problem?the actuall problem i wanted to ask is with these initials condition

Comment: Are you asking which is correct? That is, using $x \ge 0$ or $y \ge 0$, for example.  Regards

Comment: yes i want to ask the same

Comment: please someone response

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your solutions need to be functions of $x_0$ and $y(x_0)$.

Since $\dot{y}(x) \ge 0$, it is clear that $y$ is non-decreasing for $x \ge x_0$.

First I will deal with $y(x_0) >0$. Then it is clear that $\dot{y}(x) > 0$, hence $y(x) \ge y(x_0) $ for all $x \ge x_0$.

Then there is a unique solution $y(x) = (\frac{1}{2}(x-x_0)+ \sqrt{y(x_0)})^2$.

If $y(x_0) = 0$, two solutions are $y(x) = 0$ and $y(x) = (\frac{1}{2}(x-x_0))^2$.

If $y(x_0) <0$, then the solution is $y(x) = -(\frac{1}{2}(x_0-x)+ \sqrt{-y(x_0)})^2$, and this is valid for $x \in [x_0, x_0+2 \sqrt{-y(x_0)})$. For $x \ge x_0+2 \sqrt{-y(x_0)}$, the two solutions described above apply (with appropriate changes for $x_0$, of course). The solutions is unique on $[x_0, x_0+2 \sqrt{-y(x_0)})$.

Comment: sir please tell me about the editted  problem and thanks for this answer

Comment: I have given all possible answers for all $x_0$ and all $y(x_0)$. If $x_0 = 0$ and $y(x_0) = 0$, then the two solutions are $y(x) = 0$ and $y(x) = \frac{1}{4} x^2$, for $x \ge 0$.

Comment: thanks sir is then y(x)=-$\frac{x^2}\4$.

Comment: Was that a rhetorical question?

Comment: what is rhetorical question

Comment: http://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/rhetorical

Comment: thanks sir ,i was confusing why we take conditions on x not on y    sir can you tell me about a source that questions on existence and uniqueness of solutions.

Comment: Kolmogorov & Fomin, "Real Analysis" has the basic existence and uniqueness theorem.

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/10882/discussion-between-abc-and-copper-hat)

Answer (score 0):

\begin{align}
{\rm d}\sqrt{\left\vert y\right\vert\,}
&=
{1 \over 2\sqrt{\left\vert y\right\vert\,}}\,\,{\rm sgn}\left(y\right){\rm d}y
\\[3mm]
{{\rm d}y \over \sqrt{\left\vert y\right\vert\,}}
&=
2{\rm sgn}\left(y\right){\rm d}\sqrt{\left\vert y\right\vert\,}
=
2{\rm d}\left[{\rm sgn}\left(y\right)\sqrt{\left\vert y\right\vert\,}\right]
-
2\sqrt{\left\vert y\right\vert\,}\,\left[2\delta\left(y\right)\right]
=
2{\rm d}\left[{\rm sgn}\left(y\right)\sqrt{\left\vert y\right\vert\,}\right]
\end{align}

$$
2{\rm sgn}\left(y\right)\sqrt{\left\vert y\right\vert\,}
-
2{\rm sgn}\left(y_{0}\right)\sqrt{\left\vert y_{0}\right\vert\,}
=
x - x_{0}
$$
$$
\sqrt{\left\vert y\right\vert\,}
=
{\rm sgn}\left(y\right)\left[%
{\rm sgn}\left(y_{0}\right)\,\sqrt{\left\vert y_{0}\right\vert\,}
+
{1 \over 2}\,\left(x - x_{0}\right)
\right]
$$

$$
\left\vert y\right\vert
=
\left[%
{\sqrt{\left\vert y_{0}\right\vert\,}
+
{1 \over 2}\,\rm sgn}\left(y_{0}\right)\left(x - x_{0}\right)
\right]^{2}
$$

$$
\begin{array}{|c|}\hline\\
\color{#ff0000}{\large\quad%
y
\color{#000000}{\ =\ }
{\rm sgn}\left(y\right)\left[%
{\sqrt{\left\vert y_{0}\right\vert\,}
+
{1 \over 2}\,\rm sgn}\left(y_{0}\right)\left(x - x_{0}\right)
\right]^{2}
\quad}
\\ \\ \hline
\end{array}
$$